# Video.js HLS Runtime Properties

Tags: angularjs, video.js, http-live-streaming

I'm using Video.js as part of my Angular app and I'd like to to log HLS Runtime Properties such as hls.segmentXhrTime, hls.bandwidth etc.

Are there any examples of how this can be done?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Something like `console.log(player.hls.segmentXhrTime)` ?

Comment: Hi @misterben yes, exactly that. I guess I need to listen for the 'data' event like this...

`$scope.$on('$data', function(){
                console.log(player.hls.segmentXhrTime)
            });
`

but I can't seem to get it to work.